# What's the right way to perform a keyword search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-java-api

If I want to perform a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) search using a [`TermQuery`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-term-level-queries.html#java-query-dsl-term-query), what's the proper way to do this?  Am I supposed to prepend `".keyword"` to my field name?  I would think there is a more first-class citizen way of doing it! ‍♂️

```java
QueryBuilders.termQuery(SOME_FIELD_NAME + ".keyword", someValue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all boils down to your mapping. If your field is mapped as a 'straightforward' `keyword` like so

```json
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "some_field": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you won't need to append `.keyword` -- you'd do just

```
QueryBuilders.termQuery(SOME_FIELD_NAME, someValue)
```

---

It's good practice, though, not to restrict yourself to only `keyword`s, esp. if you'll be doing partial matches, expansions, autocomplete etc down the line.

A typical `text` field mapping would look like

```json
PUT kwds
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "some_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {          <---
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "analyzed": {         <---
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "simple"
          },
          "...": {              <---
             ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This means you'd be able to access differently-indexed "versions" (fields) of the same "property" (field). The naming is rather confusing but you get the gist.

Long story short, this is where the `.keyword` convention stems from. You don't need it if your field is already mapped as a `keyword`.

Comment: Appreciate the insight Joe  but the Java question still stands.  Isn’t this backed into their API in some way? 

Comment: `.keyword` is just a convention of having applied the `keyword` analyzer onto a field.